How to not output any stage when 4017 clock in is off?
I have this following schematics I made:
When I switch off SW1 the sequence will stay on the last stage that was ON. how can I make all stages to be LOW when SW1 is Off?




simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. A possible solution using existing components.

When in the STOP position SW1 grounds the CLK signal while R1 limits the output current from the 7555. Meanwhile the GND connection for the LEDs has been removed and they will turn off.
In the RUN position the CLK will receive pulses again and continue running from where it stopped. Meanwhile the LEDs will have a GND connection.

You need to check one thing on the 4017: Let's say Q3 is high and all the other outputs are low. That means that D4 is forward biased and all the others are reverse biased. Generally LEDs don't have a problem with reverse bias up to 5 V but I note that you have a 9 V battery. This may or may not be an issue for you!

Thanks but for some reason sequence is stuck on the first steps without stepping forward

This is a very creative solution, +1

"...  is stuck on the first steps ..." What does this mean? It can only stick on one step, not many. Update your schematic and post it as an update to your original question (leaving the original there so that readers can understand the history and the existing answers).

The 4017 does not really have that capability. You could add AND gates to the outputs (2 quad gate packages).
SW1 would need to be rewired anyway- as it is shown it leaves CLK floating when it is in the N.O. position.
If you really need the sequence to stay where it was when the switch was changed you need to synchronize and/or debounce the switch. Switch bounces (or just driving the clock input low) will advance the count.
This is one of those things that is just easier to make and easier to modify with an MCU or Arduino.

The question contains how can I make all stages to be LOW when SW1 is Off?, which I thought meant to reset the 4017 when SW1 is changed to disconnect the CLK, rather than If you really need the sequence to stay where it was when the switch was changed which this answer mentions.

@ChesterGillon They are not mutually exclusive requirements. You might want to pause with the current state held and outputs disabled then resume with the same state. That's why I asked "really". Of course the 4017 is decoded so that resetting it will leave output '0' active. If you're willing to reset the state to '0' then you might need only one AND gate. Possibly the debouncing could also be avoided by using the 555 reset input and the minimum period.

What I would like is that when clock switch is OFF non of the 4017 output woll be ON. How does this possible?

It's not possible in any realistic way however you could AND one or more of the outputs with an AND gate. Or perhaps you could reserve state 0 for reset since you have several unused outputs (but there would be a delay after restoring the clock before output 1 became active). To get a complete answer we need to know exactly what happens to the state when the clock is disabled and when it is removed.

when the clock is disabled (sw1 have connection between pin 2 and 3) the 4017 will stay ON on the last step that was activate)

You have the clock input to the 4017 floating (no connection at all) when the switch is in that position. That's not acceptable for CMOS inputs. It should at least have a pullup resistor to work reliably.

If you don't use all outputs of a 1-out-of-n counter with reset, you can have all used outputs inactive by just not using the output corresponding to the reset value.
This does not allow to continue conting from the state when "the hold-signal" was applied. Which you don't explicitly require in the question.
